# CMake - Imported Library has library dependency that must come first

Tags: cmake, mingw, sdl-2

I am yet another fool who is attempting to make a decent `FindSDL2.cmake` by trying to do things "the right way".  However, I am banging my head against a wall when it comes to the following problem:

```
# SDL2main imported target.
add_library(SDL2::SDL2main UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(SDL2::SDL2main PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_MAIN_LIBRARY}")
```

The trouble is, when compiling with MinGW, SDL2main needs `-lmingw32` in order to locate `WinMain`.  And it *must* come before `SDL2main` in the linker flags.

It seems like the happy path wants me to do this:

```
if(MINGW)
    set_target_properties(SDL2::SDL2main PROPERTIES
                          INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES mingw32)
endif()
```

But that doesn't work, because `mingw32` comes *after* `SDL2main` on the linker command.  It needs to be *before*.  I also would prefer not to burden targets with inserting it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this took me a little bit to figure out - thanks to ngladitz on #cmake IRC for some clarifications.

I ended up with a three step workaround:

1. Set up the SDL2main library as a new, separate target, in my case called `SDL2::_SDL2main_detail`.
2. Link this separate target directly against `SDL2::SDL2`.  This is important, otherwise CMake will mix up the link ordering of SDL2 and SDL2main.
3. Create the `SDL2::SD2main` target that just points at `mingw32` and links against `SDL2::_SDL2main_detail`.

Here is my code:

```
# SDL2main imported target.
if(MINGW)
    # Gross hack to get mingw32 first in the linker order.
    add_library(SDL2::_SDL2main_detail UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(SDL2::_SDL2main_detail PROPERTIES
                          IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_MAIN_LIBRARY}")

    # Ensure that SDL2main comes before SDL2 in the linker order.  CMake
    # isn't smart enough to keep proper ordering for indirect dependencies
    # so we have to spell it out here.
    target_link_libraries(SDL2::_SDL2main_detail INTERFACE SDL2::SDL2)

    add_library(SDL2::SDL2main INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(SDL2::SDL2main PROPERTIES
                          IMPORTED_LIBNAME mingw32)
    target_link_libraries(SDL2::SDL2main INTERFACE SDL2::_SDL2main_detail)
else()
    add_library(SDL2::SDL2main UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(SDL2::SDL2main PROPERTIES
                          IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_MAIN_LIBRARY}")
endif()
```